# How do I convert json string to protobuf message object?

Tags: json, scala, gson, protocol-buffers

```
message Example {
    enum State {
        Deleted = 1;
        Inactive = 2;
        Active = 4;
    }

    optional uint64 id                       = 1        [(gson_name) = "id"];
    optional uint64 state                    = 2        [(gson_name) = "state"];
    optional uint64 userId                   = 3        [(gson_name) = "uui"];
    optional sint32 marketId                 = 4        [(gson_name) = "m"];
    optional uint64 productId                = 5        [(gson_name) = "p"];
}
```

Json String

```
v: String = {"m": 97, "state": 1, "uui": 1, "id": 1, "p": 1}
```

Call to convert using json that fails.

```
gson.fromJson(v, classOf[Example])
```

Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

I am not sure if this is a correct way of converting json to generated proto class. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong or perhaps suggest some other method to accomplish this. I am on protobuf version 2.6 and can't really move upto 3 for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have the Java class generated for Message object. You can use the below code if you have the Java class generated for Proto Message in OP.

The below code write the PROTO message to file. You can comment that if you don't need it.

**Code to convert JSON to protobuf message object and write to file:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonString = "{\"m\": 97, \"state\": 1, \"uui\": 1, \"id\": 1, \"p\": 1}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);

        ExampleProto.Example.Builder example = ExampleProto.Example.newBuilder();       
        example.setId(jsonObject.get("id").getAsLong());
        example.setMarketId(jsonObject.get("m").getAsInt());
        example.setProductId(jsonObject.get("p").getAsInt());
        example.setState(jsonObject.get("state").getAsInt());
        example.setUserId(jsonObject.get("uui").getAsInt());

        System.out.println(example.build());

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("proto.txt"));
        example.build().writeTo(output);
        output.close();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to get json deserialized into object of java class generated for my protobuf message. I would probably use spray's json library instead of gson if I have to convert to intermediate representation anyways.

Comment: It is not advisable to change the proto Java class generated to add annotation to mention different attribute names. So, parsed the json using attribute names and mapped it to PROTO java class.